# Removing Date From Date/Time Column

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I have a column, [RESULT_DT_TM] which contains both date and time values. It looks like like this:

```
     RESULT_DT_TM
 2015-04-27  12:54:02
 2015-04-27  13:34:07
```

I would like the column to look like this:

```
     RESULT_DT_TM
       12:54:02
       13:34:07
```

Comment: Try `CAST( RESULT_DT_TM AS  time(0))`

Comment: Do you want change the result in the select or the type on the table?

Comment: Thanks all, the CAST( RESULT_DT_TM AS time(0)) code provided by @Dan Guzman works the best!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply

```
SELECT CAST(RESULT_DT_TM AS TIME) RESULT_DT_TM 
FROM YourTable
```

**Returns:**

```
+--------------+
| RESULT_DT_TM |
+--------------+
| 12:54:02     |
| 13:34:07     |
+--------------+
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=363d5579d15c190152572f7f3d0161c3)**